# In Python, how to check if words in a string are keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python

For a class I am talking the twitter sentiment analysis problem. I have looked at the other questions on the site and they don't help for my particular issue.

I am given a string that is one tweet with its letters changed so that they are all in lowercase. For example,

```
'after 23 years i still love this place. (@ tel aviv kosher pizza) http://t.co/jklp0uj'
```

as well as a dictionary of words where the key is the word and the value is the value for the sentiment for that word. To be more specific, a key can be a single word (such as 'hello'), more than one word separated by a space (such as 'yellow hornet'), or a hyphenated compound word (such as '2-dimensional'), or a number (such as '365').

I need to find the sentiment of the tweet by adding the sentiments for every eligible word and dividing by the number of eligible words (by eligible word, I mean word that is in the dictionary). I'm not sure what's the best way to go about checking if a tweet has a word in the dictionary.

---

I tried using the "key in string" convention with looping through all the keys, but this was problematic because there are a lot of keys and word-in-words would be counted (e.g. eradicate counts cat, ate, era, etc. as well)

I then tried using .split(' ') and looping through the elements of the resultant list but I ran into problems because of punctuation and keys which are two words.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can more suitably tackle this?

For example: using the example above, still : -0.625, love : 0.625, every other word is not in the dictionary.  so this should return (-0.625 + 0.625)/2 = 0.

Comment: @styvanesoukossi I did.

Comment: can you show the key in this input and expected output??

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of dictionaries is that they are quick at looking things up:

```
for word in instring.split():
   if wordsdict.has_key(word):
       print word
```

You would probably do better at getting rid of punctuation, etc, (thank-you Soke), by using regular expressions rather than split, e.g.

```
for word in re.findall(r'[\w]', instring):
    if wordsdict.get(word) is not None:
       print word
```

Of course you will have to have some maximum length of word groupings, possibly generated with a single run through of the dictionary and then take your pairs, triples, etc. and also check them.

Comment: i think its `has_key` and its depreciated in python 3

Comment: I believe that this does not fix the issue of punctuation. For example, in the above example, we will have 'pizza)'. If the dictionary had "pizza" as a word, it wouldn't realize because it would be searching for 'pizza)'.

Comment: @Hackaholic addressed in second example

Comment: Surely you want `word in wordsdict` rather than using `has_key` or `get`. `word.lower()` isn't needed as the tweet string has already been made all lower case.

Answer (score 0):

going by length of the dictionary key might be one solution.

For example, you have the dict as:

```
Sentimentdict = {"habit":5, "bad habit":-1}
```

the sentence might be:

s1="He has good habit"
   s2="He has bad habit"

s1 should be getting good sentiment compare to s2. Now, you can do this:

```
for w in sorted(Sentimentdict.keys(), key=lambda x: len(x)):
    if w in s1:
       remove the word and do your sentiment calculation
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `nltk` its very powerfull what you want to do, it can be done by `split` too:

```
>>> import string
>>> a= 'after 23 years i still love this place. (@ tel aviv kosher pizza) http://t.co/jklp0uj'
>>> import nltk
>>> my_dict = {'still' : -0.625, 'love' : 0.625}
>>> words = nltk.word_tokenize(a)
>>> words
['after', '23', 'years', 'i', 'still', 'love', 'this', 'place.', '(', '@', 'tel', 'aviv', 'kosher', 'pizza', ')', 'http', ':', '//t.co/jklp0uj']
>>> sum(my_dict.get(x.strip(string.punctuation),0) for x in words)/2
0.0
```

using `split`:

```
>>> words = a.split()
>>> words
['after', '23', 'years', 'i', 'still', 'love', 'this', 'place.', '(@', 'tel', 'aviv', 'kosher', 'pizza)', 'http://t.co/jklp0uj']
>>> sum(my_dict.get(x.strip(string.punctuation),0) for x in words)/2
0.0
```

`my_dict.get(key,default)`, so `get` will return value if key is found in dictionary else it will return default. In this case '0'

check this example: you asked for `place`

```
>>> import string
>>> my_dict = {'still' : -0.625, 'love' : 0.625,'place':1}
>>> a= 'after 23 years i still love this place. (@ tel aviv kosher pizza) http://t.co/jklp0uj'
>>> words = nltk.word_tokenize(a)
>>> sum(my_dict.get(x.strip(string.punctuation),0) for x in words)/2
0.5
```

Comment: Thanks I will look into nltk. Though the problem I was having with split seems to still be occuring with nltk. Namely, if 'place' had a sentiment value, it wouldn't be detected with either method because it is 'place.' rather than 'place'.

Comment: yes you got it now, NLTK can do better and more accurate

Comment: u can do then strip for more accurate

Comment: @Soke check the edit now it will detect 'place.' too